# how can i take a picture with out user interface by using objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, camera, automation

I want to write an automatic photographic app that can run in the background. Can anyone tell me how to do.

i have tried AVFoundation. but still not work. i don't see any app like this. so, i think it is very difficult or impossible?

someone tell me this:

```
NSLog(@"staring......\n");
UIImagePickerController *pic = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[pic setTitle:@"take a photp"];
//[pic setDelegate:self];
[pic setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
//pic.showsCameraControls = NO ;
NSLog(@"input conmand\n(t)");
[pic takePicture];
```

and i run it on my iPhone, just nothing happened.

please help me, guys.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for an app to take pictures in the background for privacy reasons. There are currently no api for this and any app that finds a way to do so will get rejected from the App Store.

Comment: thank you for answer. but i just want to run this app on my jailbreak device. just like run a binary file. it's impossible>?